# Error: The selector "" did not match any elements

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am adding routing in angular 2 below is my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { Home } from './pages/pages';
import { Dashboard } from './pages/pages';
import {ValidationError} from './validators/validators';
import { AuthService } from './services/services';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: Home },
];


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule , ReactiveFormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent , Home, Dashboard ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent , Home, Dashboard ],
  providers:    [ ValidationError ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and below is my home page which resides in pages directory.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder , FormGroup, Validators , FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';

import {ValidationError} from '../../validators/validators';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'app/pages/home/home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/pages/home/home.scss']
})

export class Home{
    serverError: any;
    bankAccount: FormGroup;

    constructor(private validationError: ValidationError , private formBuilder: FormBuilder){
        this.bankAccount = this.formBuilder.group({
            username: ['' , Validators.required]
        });
    };

    ngOnInit(){
        this.bankAccount.valueChanges.debounceTime(400).subscribe(data => this.validationError.populateErrorMessage(this.bankAccount));
    }

    login(){
        debugger
    }
}
```

But i am getting below error,

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in :0:0 caused by: The selector "home" did not match any elements ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ViewWrappedError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: The selector "home" did not match any elements
>       at ViewWrappedErr…, _nativeError: ZoneAwareError, originalError: ZoneAwareError, context: DebugContext, __zone_symbol__stack: "Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: The selector "home…st:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:241:32)"…} Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: The selector "home" did not match any elements

Any help will be apperciated.

Comment: What di you try to select with 'home' selector?

Comment: I am very new to angular 2, i am not selecting anything with home. 

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'app/pages/home/home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/pages/home/home.scss']
})
Thats it.

Comment: don't make yourself guilty by not posting the source code.

Comment: Unless you're programatically instantiating your `home` component it's best not to have it in your bootstrap components https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/appmodule.html#!#main

Comment: Resolved it thanks the mistake was in front me all the time 
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent , Home, Dashboard ] .

Answer (score 18):

Assuming your `AppComponent` is your shell component, only it should be bootstrapped. Remove `Home` and `Dashboard` from the `bootstrap` array, so your `@NgModule` looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, Home, Dashboard ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [ ValidationError ]
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the `/src/index.php` file, if the HTML prefix is correct:

from  `<app-root> </app-root>` 
to    `<home> </home>`